# RPart Table-all arguments must have the same length

Tags: r

I am trying Classify the iris data but when I am trying to plot my predictions using `table(pred,iris_test$Species)`. I am getting an error message. When I do the same thing using C50 I am not getting the error message. If anyone has faced the similar issue can you please help me Version of R-3.4.0

Error Message:

> Error in table(pred, iris_test$Species) : all arguments must have the same length

```
data("iris")
View(iris)
set.seed(123)
samp<-sample(nrow(iris),0.6*nrow(iris))
iris_train<-iris[samp,]
iris_test<-iris[-samp,]
library(rpart)
fit<-rpart(Species~.,data=iris_train,method="class")
fancyRpartPlot(fit)
pred<-predict(fit,newdata = iris_test)
table(pred,iris_test$Species)
```

Comment: try `pred<-predict(fit,newdata = iris_test, type="vector")`. the default pred.rpart type is "prob" which outputs a data.frame of probabilities. table does not know what to do with it

Comment: Thanks you issue is resolved now:)